# How configure optimize imports on the fly without rearrange import statements?

Tags: java, sorting, import, coding-style, intellij-idea

In intellij Idea it is possible to configure imports optimization on the fly, if this configuration set, IDE will delete unused imports and sort them. But is it possible to enable import optimization on the fly but without sorting imports? For example I do not want to highlight unnecessary changing in code review system, that mark rearranged import statements as changes code lines.
So is it possible to optimization imports without sorting?

Answer (score 7):

The "Optimize imports on the fly" option doesn't have a "rearrange entries" option to turn off. The Settings dialog has some configuration under *Code Style* -> *Java* -> *Imports tab* that might be helpful (the optimizer will be using this configuration). At the very least, you can probably reduce the amount of optimization done by playing with those settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am personally not using `Intellij Idea` at the moment, but take a look at the following links that descripe the functionality offered by `Intellij Idea` concerning Imports:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/optimizing-imports.html

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/optimize-imports-dialog.html
(take a look at `Rearrange entries`)

Comment: This is about optimize dialog, which you **must** call each time when you need to optimize imports. I ask about on the **fly optimization** which performs on each key action when you edit java file. **P.S.** I think it is not correct to answer an a question in way like "I do not use, do not try, but check the links".

Comment: Ah ok didn't realize that is something different. 
Hmm yea that might be true... Will try to watch out to not comment if im not sure in the future :)